# Default select Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

```
 <select class="ui search dropdown" ng-model="vm.empresa" ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in vm.collectionData.items track by item.id" required >
   <option value="">Selecione uma Empresa</option>
 </select>
```

Como faço para deixar o primeiro item já selecionado por default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça um `ng-init` para selecionar o primeiro elemento:

```
<select class="ui search dropdown" ng-init="vm.empresa = vm.collectionData.items[0]" ng-model="vm.empresa" ng-options="item.id as item.label for item in vm.collectionData.items track by item.id" required >
   <option value="">Selecione uma Empresa</option>
 </select>
```

assim seu model vai receber o primeiro item da lista.

Comment: Testei com o seu código, e com algumas variações dele mas não consegui o resultado esperado.

Comment: Esse código só funcionará se `vm.collectionData` já estiver carregado quando o controle inicializar.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro vc adiciona o módulo em 'app.modules.ts' seguinte comando:

```
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
```

No @NgModules adicione o módulo:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,    
  ],
  imports: [
    MatSelectModule,
        
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Feito isso crie no HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>ANO</mat-label>
    <mat-select placeholder="2023" [(value)]="selected" #clientValue (selectionChange)="opcaoSelecionada($event.value)">
        <mat-option [value]=2020>2020</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=2021>2021</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=2022>2022</mat-option>
        <mat-option [value]=2023>2023</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-hint align="end">Selecione o ano</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

No typescript:

```
value: any = 2023;
  selected = 2023;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.opcaoSelecionada(this.value)
  }

  opcaoSelecionada(value: any) {

    this.servico.chamaTabela().subscribe(data => {

      this.listaTabela = data;

      this.lista = this.listaTabela[Number(value) - 2020][Number(value)]
    })
  }
```